# the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^{n}_K$ is discrete iff $K$ is finite field.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Suppose that $K$ is a finite field, then the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^{n}_K$ is discrete. Show that it is never true if $K$ is an infinite field.

Suppose that $K$ is a finite field, then consider any singleton set $T=\{(a_1,a_2 \dots a_n)\}$ of $\mathbb{A}^{n}_K$. Then I claim that $T$ is a closed subset.
To see that consider the set of polynomials $$T=\{x_i-a_i : i=1,2,3 \dots n \} $$. Then $V(S)=T$ which proves that $T$ is a closed subset. Further since our set over which the topology is being defined is a finite set, it has the discrete topology.

Now I am unable to do the subproblem which asks us to show that this is never the case when $K$ is an infinite field. How should I show that? I thought that showing a particular set is not of the form of $V(S)$ would work, because the sets of the form $V(I)$ satisfy the closed set definition of a topology, but I am unable to find a set and prove the desired result. I am considering the set of the form $S=\{a,a,a \dots a : a\in K\}$ but I am stuck.

Will the following work?

Consider $S=\{a,a,a \dots a : a\in K\}$ is a closed set, then $S=\{a,a,a \dots a : a\in K\}=V(I)$, then $I=\{f(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n) : f(a,a, \dots a )=0 \text{ for all } a \in K \}$. Choose any element $f(x_1,x_2 \dots x_n ) \in I$, then $f(a,a \dots a)=0 \Rightarrow x-a | f(x_1,a \dots a) $ for all $a \in K$. Since the cardinality of the field being considered here is infinite and any polynomial here is finite degree, implies $f(x)=0 \Rightarrow \! \Leftarrow$. The division algorithm works because we are working in a field and any field is an euclidean domain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of a solution: reduce to the case of $\Bbb A^1$. Now classify the closed subsets of $\Bbb A^1_k$ (hint: use the coordinate algebra; see the related questions in the sidebar if you're stuck on this bit). Think about what would need to happen for that topology to be the discrete topology.

A bigger hint:

> When is the cofinite topology the discrete topology? Look at the intersection of any two open subsets.

It's important to note that this situation is unique to the situation of "classical varieties" - the scheme $\Bbb A^1_k$ is irreducible for any field $k$, exactly as one would expect.